# Fingerprint Reader Driver for Dell XPS 13 9370

Tags: drivers, usb, 22.04, dell, fingerprint-reader

my Ubuntu Laptop reports a Goodix Fingerprint Reader

```
lsusb output: Bus 001 Device 004: ID 27c6:5385 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
```

and I found a driver (libfprint-2-tod1-goodix) which is reported to support the fingerprint readers with the modaliases `hwe(usb:v27C6p533C*, usb:v27C6p538C*, usb:v27C6p530C*, usb:v27C6p5840*)`. This obviously includes `usb:v27C6p538C*` but not `usb:v27C6p5385*`.

[linux-hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=17304074a6) at least reports the device with id `27c6:5385` as "detected".

I dpkg-installed the driver and made sure, that `fprintd.service` is running (after reboot). but `fprintd-enroll` still reports an error (`GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available`).

What can I do?